# How to proxy traffic by IP using server names/aliases?

Tags: domain-name-system, proxy, load-balancing, http, haproxy

We have 5 different server locations each containing around 30 servers each, each server represents a URL and serves both HTTP and HTTPS. They're all identical however provide different content based on where they chose to see content from, they're able to select regional content by changing their user settings and we have them tied to bind views in DNS.

We have a DNS server that resolves names to IP addresses according to their location and sends the traffic to them. It works great, however when someone changes a region, several things are cached between the user/browser/os/etc, mostly DNS stuff.

What we'd like to do is use all the same IP addresses for each domain name, and have everything resolve to a set of HAProxy servers that will internally proxy/route the traffic to based on their ip  and user configurations. This way, DNS will always point them to the same front end servers and allowing their DNS to cache everything.

I figured I could do this with HAProxy, so when the client connects to blog.test.com it creates a proxy inside the front-end servers to say our South African site blog.test.com - however, it would need to do it by IP address otherwise the DNS would get confused..

Can I setup HAProxy to accept connections for blog.test.com and internally connect to 1.2.3.4 and pass along any headers like site name/alias?

Comment: HAproxy will **always** pass the unaltered request along to whatever webserver/appserver you choose, unless you tell it to mangle the request. Your post is a little hard to decipher, because you mix lots of terms that are a bit ambiguous. If I understand you right, you want HAproxy to select a specific server IP based on the domain that the client requested, independently of DNS, yes?

Comment: thats right, so we'd like to have say a request go through DNS and find our front end "www.abc.com" server, and that front end server would just pass the request through to a specific IP address (not requiring/using a fqdn) to fulfill the request. So a connection coming into "www.abc.com" can be handed off to say "1.2.3.4" or "4.5.6.7". Would this work with SNI devices as well?

Comment: SNI is a whole different discussion that is apparently led [in your other question](http://serverfault.com/questions/623971/multiple-proxy-servers-and-how-to-get-around-non-sni-devices), yes? - I can forumulate an answer, but I still don't understand on what basis the the choice among say "1.2.3.4" or "4.5.6.7" should be made by haproxy.

Comment: We will use an ACL for the decision choosing an IP address. The acl will be based on the clients IP.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This `haproxy` config will route the connections through to your sites, unmolested.

```
frontend portal
    # site 1
    bind 12.13.14.15:80
    bind 12.13.14.15:443
    # site 2
    bind 12.13.14.16:80
    bind 12.13.14.16:443
    # ...

    mode tcp

    acl site1 dst 12.13.14.15
    acl site2 dst 12.13.14.16
    ...
    acl ssl dst_port 443

    acl region1 src 82.0.0.0/7
    ...

    use_backend site1_india_ssl if site1 region1 ssl
    use_backend site1_india     if site1 region1
    use_backend site1_south_africa_ssl if site1 region2 ssl
    use_backend site1_south_africa if site1 region2
    ...
    use backend site2_india_ssl if site2 region1 ssl
    ...
```

You define each server in each location in a distinct backend, such as `site1_india`, each with an SSL variant to use port 443.

`mode http` would work, but I don't see how it would help you. You would have to decrypt all SSL, **and** re-encrypt it for safe forwarding to the respective site.

Also note that with this design, latencies will be prohibitive for the clients that are topologically far away from the `haproxy` instance, because their packages will likely make a round trip to the proxy, and back to the local appservers (that are likely close to the client).

You can probably offset this by adding an `haproxy` instance to each location, so that clients will usually use a local proxy (except they relocate and rely on cached DNS).