# Multiple Proxy servers - and how to get around non-SNI devices?

Tags: proxy, load-balancing, http, https, haproxy

We have a lot of devices that cannot use SNI and we want to be able to proxy a lot of HTTP/HTTPS servers. I was thinking we could setup a HAProxy for each URL to connect to initially, and then load balance it off to a generic HAProxy server. Would this work? I mean, just use the front end servers to do the HTTP/HTTPS initial connection per URL and then pass the request off to a generic haproxy server?

Comment: I'm not quite sure you understand how SNI works. You need _IP addresses_, or at least a certificate with a lot of alternate names. No proxy is going to help you here. Of course, you should upgrade or decommission the misbehaving devices as soon as possible.

Comment: We have an IP address for each HAProxy server, as well as a certificate. We just want to be able to pass the connection off to a "generic" haproxy server after the device connects.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Yes, although haproxy would almost be overkill for this. You could even bind an `stunnel` with the appropriate certificate to each IP address and make those connect to your central HAproxy.

There's not even need to have more than one HAproxy.

```
listen ssl-domain1
    bind public-ip-1:443
    # <- ssl config here ->
    server haproxy localhost:6000

listen ssl-domain2
    bind public-ip-2:443
    # <- ssl config here ->
    server haproxy localhost:6000

 ... # more ssl listeners

 frontend http-proxy
     bind localhost:6000
     acl application1 hdr_beg(host) -i domain1
     acl application1 hdr_beg(host) -i domain1.2
     acl application2 hdr_beg(host) -i domain2
     # ...
     use_backend application1 if application1
     # ...
```

Not especially pretty, but would get the job done, I believe.